# Concat results of single function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

```
const example = e => {
        console.log(e);
    };
```

Each time an API call is made, `example()` or rather `e` gives back different strings, such as:

`string one`
`string two`
`string three`

Is there a way to concat all these strings into one array?

Comment: `let arr = []; const example = str => { arr.push(str) };` Don't call the var `e` - most everybody use that for event like we use `i` for index

Comment: There is. Just push to an array, and then you can concat the array when you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];
const example = e => {
  arr.push(e);
  console.log(e);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare somewhere an array and push the values there.

```js
let arr = [];
const example = item => {
        arr.push(item);
        console.log(arr);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend to use a function that sends your requests, e.g. `sendRequest()`. If you access a database or some website you have to declare an `async` function, because it's unsure, when you get your response back. Your `sendRequest` function can then return a javascript object either if the api call was successful or not. The keyword `await` waits, until the promise is resolved.

Now to your question: If your call was successful, just push your result to an outer defined array `apiResults`, thats it.

```js
const apiResults = [];

async function sendRequest() {
  try {
    const apiResult = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    const apiSuccess = Boolean(apiResult);
    
    if (apiSuccess) {
      apiResults.push(apiResult);
    }
    return { ok: apiSuccess, data: apiResult }; 
  } catch (err) {
    return { ok: false, data: {} };
  }
}

(async function test() {
  console.log('Before', apiResults);
  const response = await sendRequest();
  console.log('After', apiResults);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```